# Find the maximum possible summation of differences of consecutive elements

Tags: java, algorithm, array, recursion, dynamic-programming

> Array A contains the elements, \$A_1,A_2, \ldots, A_N\$.
>    And array B contains the elements, \$B_1,B_2, \ldots, B_N\$.
>
> There is a relationship between \$A_i\$ and \$B_i\$: any element \$A_i\$ lies between \$1\$ and \$B_i\$.
>
> Let the cost S of an array A be defined as:
>
> $$ S = \sum_{i=2}^N \lvert A_i - A_{i-1} \rvert$$
>
> Given B, find and print the largest possible value of S.

The problem can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-cost)

**Example**:

`size of array`:5
`array`: 10 1 10 1 10
`output` : 36
(since the max value can be derived as |10 - 1| + |1 - 10| + |10 - 1| + |1 - 10|)

**Approach**:
The only approach I could think of was brute force. I thought I would make an overlapping recursive equation so that I could memoize it, but was not able to.

**CODE**:

```java
public static void func(int pos,int[] arr,int[] aux,int n)
    {
        /*
         * pos is current index in the arr
         * arr is array
         * aux is temp array which will store one possible combination.
         * n is size of the array.
         * */



        //if reached at the end, check the summation of differences
        if(pos == n)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                //System.out.print("i = " + i + ", arr[i] = " + aux[i] + " ");
                sum += Math.abs(aux[i] - aux[i - 1]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
            if(sum > max)
            {
                max = sum;
            }
            return;
        }

        //else try every combination possible.
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= arr[pos] ; i++)
        {
            aux[pos] = i;
            func(pos + 1,arr,aux,n);
        }
}
```

**NOTE**:
The complexity of this is \$\mathcal{O}(n*2^n)\$

Answer (score 2):

The above can be optimized by using two things.

1. Memorizing the result of the `func()`.  To implement memorizing you need to send some response from the func which can be memorized for certain parameters. In your cases it wouldn't be possible. You need to change the `func` defination to implement memorizing.
2. Pre-processing on array B to calculate minimum till any `i` and maximum till any `i`.

> Explaining 2nd point in detail, at any point of three possible
>   combination of \$A_{i-1}, A_i\$ and \$A_{i+1}\$
>
> \$A_i > A_{i-1}, A_{i+1}\$, In this case it makes sense to choose \$A_i\$ as the max value in B till i
>
> \$A_i < A_{i-1},A_{i+1}\$, In this case it makes sense to choose \$A_i\$ as the min value in B till i
>
> \$A_{i-1} < A_i < A_{i+1}\$, In this case you can see \$A_i\$ would have any involvement in final sum. It is getting cancelled out. So even if we choose \$A_{i-1}\$ or \$A_{i+1}\$ as \$A_i\$ it will also give same result. 
>   Hence it makes sense to pick either min or max value at any point from B.

You can try below solution with both of the above optimization.

```
possible_sum[][] = new Integer[n][2] // An array which memorize maximum possible sum till any n
initially possible_sum to some default value '-1'

int find_possible_sum(int i, int next, int minORmax){
    if(possible_sum[i][minORmax] != -1)return possible_sum[i][minORmax];
    possible_sum[i][minORmax] =  max(find_possible_sum(i-1, max_till_i, 0) + abs(max_till_i - next), find_possible_sum(i-1, minTill_i, 1)) + abs(min_till_i - next)); 
   // max_till_i and min_till_i can obtained in O(n) during pre-calculation
   return possible_sum[i][minORmax];
}




int max_value = -1 , min_value = MAX_VALUE;
   int min_till_i[], max_till_i[]; 
   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        min_till_i[i] = min(B[i],min_value);
        min_value = min(min_value, B[i]);

        max_till_i[i] = max(B[i],max_value);
        max_value = min(max_value, B[i]);
    }
```

Total complexility of this solution should be around: \$O(n)\$ + \$O(2*n)\$